# Range-based loop, unique pointers, and move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr

Here is the a code similar to one I have:

```
for (auto &uptr : vector_of_unique_ptrs) {              // 1
  auto result = do_the_job_with_pointee(uptr.get());    // 2
  record_intermidiate_result(result, std::move(uptr));  // 3
}
```

Here I have a vector of unique pointers to some objects (line 1).

I iterate over the vector (line 1) and do some work using the pointee (line 2).

After the job is done I need to take a result and pass the ownership to some other place (line 3).

The code compiles and executes without any problems, but I have feeling that it's not legal to move iteratee during iteration.

I "skimmed" though publicly available C++11 draft, but didn't find any clarifications on the subject.

Could anybody tell me is the code above legal or not?

Comment: Your vector will have `nullptr` `unique_ptr`.

Comment: you should not invalidate vector iterators ie call `erase()` `insert()` etc. Modifying elements is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, now I get it. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (auto &uptr : vector_of_unique_ptrs)
```

'uptr' is now a reference to a unique_ptr of whatever type you made it. 'uptr' is not an iterator in this case. So, your code is safe as it is not actually messing with the iterator.

Now, if you had written code like this:

```
for(auto iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); iter++)
```

that would be a different story. Using std::move on this 'iter' in the middle of the loop would be problematic and probably not what you would want anyway. But using your code is safe as far as the vector and loop are concerned. In fact, here are a couple other ways to look at your code:

```
//I'm calling your vector_of_unique_ptrs 'vec' for brevity
//and I'm assuming unique_ptr<int> just 'cause

//This works
for (auto iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); iter++) {
  unique_ptr<int>& uptr = *iter;
  auto result = do_the_job_with_pointee(uptr.get());
  record_intermidiate_result(result, std::move(uptr));
}

//As does this
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
  unique_ptr<int>& uptr = vec[i];
  auto result = do_the_job_with_pointee(uptr.get());
  record_intermidiate_result(result, std::move(uptr));
}
```

And that's what the range-based for loop's doing; using an iterator and de-referencing it for you so you don't actually touch the iterator.

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed answer. Now the picture in my head is clear.

Answer (score 11):

Your code is absolutely legal and well-defined. Nothing prevents you from modifying elements of the sequence during iteration, and moving is just a form of modification.

Just keep in mind to not try to use those pointers after the loop.